# dynamically instantiate classes in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, class

I want to dynamically add `threading.Thread` classes to a thread `queue` based on a database query.  Is that possible?

For example:

```
import threading, Queue

class worker(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            print 'doing stuff'

# get jobs from db
jobs = list(db.Jobs.find())

q = Queue.Queue(5)
for job in jobs:
    # instantiate a worker thread here.. don't know how to do this
    ...
    # start new worker thread
    new_worker_thread.start()
    # then add the worker to the queue
    q.put(new_worker_thread)
```

Any advice would be awesome.

Comment: It's worth noting that [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (the Python style guide) recommends `CapWords` be reserved for classes, and `lowercase_with_underscores` for variables. You might want to follow this to make your code more readable.

Comment: Ahm, what's wrong about `new_worker_thread = worker()`?

Comment: oh right, because instantiating a worker with the same name doesn't overwrite the existing object.. I realise that now

Comment: Neither does `for job in jobs:` "overwrite" the existing object referred to by `job` every time it restarts the loop and gives you a different object referred to by `job`. Names are just references to objects; making a name refer to a new object does *nothing* to whatever it used to refer to. This is absolutely **fundamental** to how Python works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use:

```
new_worker_thread = worker()
```

This instantiates a new worker thread. After this you can start and put it in the queue.

Some more information on threads can be found here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Very useful tutorial!

Comment: oh right, because instantiating a worker with the same name doesn't overwrite the existing object.. I realise that now

Comment: Exactly and the reason is that you are storing the objects in a queue so you can access them later.